# Xray cloud - How to map tests to user stories and manage executions?

Tags: jira-xray

Below is step which is performed in Xray cloud

-Added two case in repository

-Added (linked) those 2 test case in a story

-created test execution and run the test make both test case passed and complete the test execution and then it shows test result passed.
My release is completed and closed.

After 2 months new release is going in and now i have to run same 2 tests as part of new release.

- Created new story for new release execution
  Now added same 2 test   case in this new story  as soon as i added test case it says test
  case is passed  its taking the old executions from 2 months before.

  So without executing tests they are failed which is not correct.  How
  do we handle this scenario? any recommendations?

Comment: To be able to help you out, can you please clarify some points?
1) are you using the Jira releases concept, where each release is identified by a different value on the "Fix Version" field? If so, do you define it on the Test Execution?
2) whenever you mentioned that you "created new story for new release" and that you added the same tests... why are you creating a new story and adding the same tests exactly? Is that user story any different from the previous one?
3) can you share a screenshot of where exactly you see the wrong status of the tests? Is it on the new user story issue screen?

Comment: 4) you mentioned that it shows tests passed and then failed. can you please clarify and elaborate a bit? Where do you see the tests passing (without executing) and where do you sem failing (without executing)? And did you do any action in between?

Answer (score 0):

If you have 2 stories linked to the same test cases, whenever you run those tests, they will contribute in the same way for the heuristic that Xray provides: the coverage status.
Therefore, if both tests pass, Xray will consider both of the user stories to be OK. This is how Xray works.

However, usually you would have different test cases linked to different user stories. Tests should be tailored for what you're trying to cover, so they're focused and to be able to identify the root cause easier and also the impacts.
If we have test cases that cover too much then it will be hard to analyze it later on.

Note that coverage status heuristic in Xray is multidimensional: you can analyze it for a specific version or for the latest results, and that will take into account just the respective results. So, you can have story1 assigned to v1, and story assigned to v2; therefore you can always filter out the stories by version in the Test Coverage report, for example, just to see the stories that matter for each version and visually workaround this.

Note: Xray datacenter has a setting related to separation of concerns, where on this use case you can report how a test contributes to the status of each user story independently; this setting doesn't exist on Xray cloud though.